# What's the different between Async.queue and Promise.map?

Tags: express

I tried to stress test my api in ExpressJS and to handler multi request I used Promise.all and then Async.queue with concurrency option.

1. Promise:

   ```
   export const myapi = async (args1, args2) => {
   console.log('args:', args1, args2);

   let testing_queue = [];
   testing_queue.push(new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
           let result = await doAComplexQuery(args1, args2); // SELECT... JOIN...
           if (!result || result.length <= 0)
               reject(new Error('Cannot find anything!'));
           resolve(result);
       }
   ));
   return await Bluebird.map(testing_queue, async item => {
       return item;
   }, {concurrency: 4});    };
   ```
2. Async.queue: (https://www.npmjs.com/package/async)

   ```
   export const myapi = async (args1, args2) => {
   console.log('args:', args1, args2);

   let testing_queue = Async.queue(function (task, callback) {
       console.log('task', task);
       callback();
   }, 4);
   testing_queue.push(async function () {
           let result = await doAComplexQuery(args1, args2); // SELECT... JOIN...
           if (!result || result.length <= 0)
               throw new Error('Cannot find anything!');
           return result;
       }
   );};
   ```

And try to make request as much as possible:

```
const response = async function () {
    return await Axios.post('http://localhost:3000/my-api', {
        "args1": "0a0759eb",
        "args2": "b9142db8"
    }, {}
    ).then(result => {
        return result.data;
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error.message);
    });
};

for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    response();
}
```

And Run. The #1 way returns many ResourceTimeout or Socket hang up responses. Meanwhile, the #2 returns success response for all requests and runs even faster.

So is the Async.queue better in this case?

Comment: What is `Async` ?

Comment: I use this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/async

Answer (score 0):

I think it could help the speed if you raise the concurrency limit on your promise.map.